# asp.mvc unit test viewresult problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to write my first test class. There is something wrong with the ViewResult.

```
var result = controller.Delete as ViewResult;
```

ViewResult is uderlined and says "the type or namespace "ViewResult"couldn't be found.."

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Bordo.WebSite.AdminUI.Controllers;
```

What am I missing?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that you have referenced the `System.Web.Mvc` assembly in your unit test and that your unit test project targets **.NET 4.0** otherwise you might not see it in the Add Reference list.

Also shouldn't this line:

```
var result = controller.Delete as ViewResult;
```

be:

```
var result = controller.Delete() as ViewResult;
```

assuming `Delete` is a controller action?

Answer (score 2):

[ViewResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewresult.aspx) is in the System.Web.Mvc namespace so you are missing:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

If its not an option you can browse to references and add a reference to `System.Web.Mvc`

What version of .NET and Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: You need to go to the project where controller.Delete resides, check the references, and see if the System.Web.Mvc references exists, and if so where it is being referenced.  (Please delete your stale comments, we have way too many right now)

Comment: Interesting, you can go to Add References, navigate to the DLL and add it.